# Quantum beats as temporal interferences : whats does that mean?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-electrodynamics, interference, superposition, elementary-particles

I've already seen the expression "temporal interference" used to designate these "quantum beats"; often to contrast with the "spatial" interference that would be manifested by the double-slit experience.
(for references, for example: *And yet it moves :strange systems and subtle questions in physics*, Cambridge University Press, Mark P. Silverman, p.74).

But I'm struggling to understand what these temporal interferences actually mean. Can someone shed some light on this?

And a supplementary question: have quantum beats been observed on the scale of a subatomic particle? Because the examples I've found only concern atoms or molecules...